# how to add multiple filters to an existing pipeline GstElement?

Tags: c, gstreamer

how can I add filters to an existing pipeline.

currently I am using an existing video file and then processing it using `gst_parse_launch`

```
gst_parse_launch("-v -m -t filesrc location=./videos/example.webm ! decodebin ! cutter threshold-dB=-39  run-length=400000000 !tee name=t ! queue ! fakesink t. ! queue ! valve name=valve ! audioconvert! audioresample !  audio/x-raw, rate=16000, channels=1  ! multifilesink location=./output/output%02d.pcm next-file=2", NULL);
```

now this is working fine.

I want to know how can I add multiple filters at once to an existing `pipeline`

I know I can do something like `audioconvert = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert", "audioconvert");`

but is there any method which will direct take multiple filters like `gst_parse_launch` method does ?

**EDIT:** currently I get an existing pipeline with audio video source, all I want to do is apply the filters which I have developed on this pipeline,
i know I can use `st_bin_add_many to add` but that will require me to so `gst_element_factory_make` but I want to know that is there any way by which i can use `gst_parse_launch` which will handle all the filter `init` and then add this new pipeline to existing audio video pipeline

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gst_bin_add_many`

The syntax would be: `(GST_BIN (existing_pipeline), filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4)`

See documentation of [gst_bin_add_many](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBin.html#gst-bin-add-many)

Comment: for this I will have to create each element using `gst_element_factory_make` and then `g_object_set`, I want to use `gst_parse_launch` which will reduce the task

Comment: well you can get your pipeline like this: `GstElement *pipeline = gst_parse_launch("-v -m -t filesrc location=./videos/example.webm ! decodebin", &error);` so once you have your pipeline now you can use the gst_bin_add_many to add whatever you want to the pipeline. You can also get specific filters from the pipeline above like: `GstElement filesrc = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "src");`

Comment: currently I get an existing pipeline with audio video source, all I want to do is apply the filters which I have developed on this pipeline,
i know I can use `st_bin_add_many to add` but that will require me to so `gst_element_factory_make` but I want to know that is there any way by which i can use `gst_parse_launch` which will handle all the filter `init` and then add this new pipeline to existing audio video pipeline

Comment: Why dont you create two pipelines then? one which will simply apply all your filters and provide either a `file` or a `udpsink` in your second pipeline read from that `udpsource`

Comment: if I am getting this right, then do you mean I can provide a pipeline to the source of the second pipeline ?

Comment: Yes, why not? just write the first pipeline to a sink whether it is a filesink or udp sink etc. Then use the other as a source to the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use gst_parse_bin_from_description() for generating a bin with elements from a pipeline description: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstParse.html#gst-parse-bin-from-description

This gives you a bin with all the elements you specified, which you then can handle as if they were a single element and add them to an existing pipeline, and link them. Note the ghost_unlinked_pads parameter though, you probably want this to be TRUE unless you ghost the pads yourself manually.

Also keep in mind that adding elements to a running pipeline requires some special case, I wrote an article about that a while ago here in case it matters for you: https://coaxion.net/blog/2014/01/gstreamer-dynamic-pipelines/

Also note that you can't pass "-m -v -t" to gst_parse_launch(). Those are parameters for the commandline gst-launch-1.0 tool, gst_parse_launch() will ignore them in the best case or might just fail.

Also keep in mind that pipelines created via pipeline descriptions are not necessarily reusable (if SOMETIMES or REQUEST pads are involved), that is you can't e.g. go to NULL state and then back to PAUSED/PLAYING and assume things still work the same. If you need this you will have to create the elements yourself manually one by one, and add them to the bin with gst_bin_add()/gst_bin_add_many() and link them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so now if I am correct I will have to add pipeline and bin using `gst_bin_add_many()` but how do I link them ?  `gst_element_link (pipeline, filterbin);` throws runtime error `assertion failed: (gst_element_link (pipeline, filterbin))`

Comment: Please read the application developer manual first: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/index.html

There seem to be a general misunderstanding of how GStreamer concepts work. In this case, you don't link elements together but pads (which might be owned by elements). And you link pads together so data can flow between the two. There's no point in linking the pipeline and the bin. If anything you want to link a pad from an element inside the pipeline to a pad on the bin.